# Migrating application to AWS Kinesis Firehose and AWS s3 multiple tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-athena, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I need to upgrade my application in order to bear streaming data. My application has a different kind of data that is stored in different MySQL `tables`.

So, I want to create an AWS `Kinesis Firehose` and AWS `Lambda function` to receive, transform and load my data to S3 in CSV file.

All the information I have found googling explains very well how to implement this but only storing the data in one unique CSV. I assume that only having one unique CSV, it will be interpreted by Athena as one table.

I have not found any information to create and store multiple CSV files using  `Kinesis Firehose` and AWS `Lambda function` (which will represent tables in Athena).

Should I create a new `Kinesis Firehose` instance for each table I have in my MySQL database? or exists some way to store these data in different CSV files?

Comment: This might be useful: [(53) How to fan-out Amazon Kinesis Streams? | LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-fan-out-amazon-kinesis-streams-alex-casalboni/)

Comment: It is not clear what do you want Kinesis Firehose for. If you are trying to migrate from MySQL to S3 (and Athena), you should check Data Migration Service (DMS). It has most of the functionalities you described.